# Uniform initialization on member initializer list error

Tags: c++, class, c++11, struct, visual-c++-2015

I am getting a compilation error on this C++11 code but I dont know why. This is the code:

```
#include <condition_variable>

class NonCopiableClass
{
    std::condition_variable condition_;
};

struct NonCopiableStruct
{
    std::condition_variable condition_;
};

class Test
{
 public:
    Test() : 
        myClass{},
        myStruct{}
    {};
 private:
    NonCopiableClass myClass;
    NonCopiableStruct myStruct;
};
```

Visual Studio 2015 fails with the following error:

> error C2280: 'std::condition_variable::condition_variable(const std::condition_variable &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
>   1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\mutex(550): note: see declaration of 'std::condition_variable::condition_variable'.

If I change the `Test constructor` to not use C++11 uniform initialization of the `Struct` it compiles OK.

```
Test() : 
        myClass{},
        myStruct() // <--- CHANGE
    {};
```

I am not getting why for `Struct` type uses copy constructor but the `Class` seems OK. It only happends with `Struct` having non-copiable members.

I also noted that if I init the `Struct` outside of the `Test Class` member initializer list It works:

```
int main()
{
    NonCopiableStruct a{};   
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea Why is this code failing?. What is going on under the hood? What is the difference between `myClass` initialization and `myStruct` initialization?. Why it won't compile if used on the class member `initializer list` but is it okay I use it outside? I have tried on `GCC` and it seems to be okay.

Comment: You don’t need to initialize them at all.

Comment: Switch to VS2017.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This seems like a MSVC bug. The difference is that the `struct` version is an aggregate, and the `class` version is not (on account of the default private access specifier).

The class version is value initialized by `{}`. The struct version is aggregate initialized. A conforming compiler should just list initialize `condition_` with `{}`, because you didn't provide an initializer for it.

But MSVC seems to be stumbling on the fact that members of an aggregate are copy initialized from the corresponding initializer in the initializer list. It seems to check for the copy c'tor, even if it isn't supposed to actually use it.

This is further supported by the fact it knows what to do when an object of the same type is initialized *outside* of a member initializer list.